# redirect to an external url but send custom POST parameters

Tags: php, symfony, post, redirect

i am trying to make a script that redirects to a site, for example paypal or coinbase, however these require post parameters, most of the time i send those with a form, however i am looking for a method that allows me to send post parameters directly from the controller and redirect the user to the external site.

I am running symfony2, and i don't wanna use forms, i have been trying to find such example online but i can't find any.

If any code is required, please don't hesitate to ask but right now i don't have a clue on how to do such.

I am new to REST apis and it's giving me quite a bit of troubles.

Comment: Did you try outputting a form then submitting it immediately with javascript?

Comment: JavaScript is the only possible solution here.

Comment: I'd rather not use javascript as its a more hacky way of accomplishing the task, i guess i must dive deeper into  the documentation to come up with a solution (it's a REST doc so i guess it's not that hard?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to include `POST` data in a redirect from PHP / symfony2.

A workaround could be using client-side JavaScript to post directly to the desired target location.

Another solution could be sending the `POST` request to the external API using `curl` in your controller and forwarding the API's response to the client.

Comment: It is not technically possible to include any data body in a redirect, this has nothing to do with php/sf2. It is done using the `Location` header, which - according to the standard - results in a get request to that url.

Comment: @Maerlyn This is not entirely correct, as you can use an HTTP 307 - though 1) I'm unsure it was the intent of 307 and 2) the user will get a "do you want to submit this form again" question from the browser. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect